# How to speed up sentence tokenization with Spacy

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-transformers

I am trying to extract the first sentences from a list of paragraphs with the following function (that I apply in a for loop):

```py
def extract_first_sentence(text):
  doc = nlp(text)
  return [sent.text for sent in doc.sents][0]
```

The code does what I want but is slow. It seems inefficient to extract all sentences first with `.text` but apparently there is no way to subset `doc.sents` directly. The tips given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597688/speed-up-spacy-tokenizer) do not really apply for the most part because I do not need to read and write files as I go. I'm using the model `"en_core_web_trf"`.